# OpenSSH on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a new (first time) CentOS 6.5 server being used for a web server.   Our security team has identified the following weakness:

The SSH server is configured to allow either MD5 or 96-bit MAC algorithms, both of which are considered weak.   Note that this plugin only checks for the options of the SSH server and does not check for vulnerable software versions.

Plugin Output The following client-to-server Method Authentication Code (MAC) algorithms  are supported :    hmac-md5   hmac-md5-96   hmac-sha1-96

How do I disable MD5 and/or 96-bit MAC algorithms on a CentOS 6.5 server?  I tried running:  authconfig --disablemd5 --updateall   but still had the same issue.

Comment: Please DO NOT cross-post on multiple SE sites. If you think a question should be on a different site, Flag it and request the migration.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the good answers I've read on the topic.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39756/secure-configuration-of-ciphers-macs-kex-available-in-ssh

But if you want to disable from the server side, the algorithms used for symmetric session encryption can be chosen in the sshd2_config files. The system will attempt to use the different encryption ciphers in the sequence specified on the line.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that but it's not really an answer it mostly says that you don't need to implement this.  I cross-posted the question on Security Exchange as well.